# html form to php array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm trying to take a string as a form input from the user and check whether it is a country or not using an array of countries. I'm now getting this error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to the Country Searcher </h1>
<form method="get">
    <p><label for="guess">Input Guess</label>
    <input type="text" name="guess" id="guess"/></p>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

    $countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", 
                "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
                "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", 
                "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
                "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", 
                "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegowina", 
                "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", 
                "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", 
                "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", 
                "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", 
                "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", 
                "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "France Metropolitan", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao, People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Helena", "St. Pierre and Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");

    if( in_array("$_GET['guess']",  $countries)) {
        echo "Your country $_GET['guess'] is valid!";
    } else {
        echo "I'm sorry! You've entered an invalid string!";
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"My idea seems to be failing:"* - Failing how? You didn't say what isn't working the way you'd like it to.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and update your question with clear details of what you have tried, the specific issues you are having and your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a lot simpler by using `in_array()`

Its also a good idea to soecify a method on a `<form>` tag. The default may be GET but if you code it, then you are self documenting your code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to the Country Searcher </h1>
<form method="get">
    <p><label for="guess">Input Guess</label>
    <input type="text" name="guess" id="guess"/></p>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

    $countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", 
                "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
                "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", 
                "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
                "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", 
                "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegowina", 
                "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", 
                "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", 
                "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", 
                "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", 
                "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", 
                "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia (Hrvatska)", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "France Metropolitan", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard and Mc Donald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao, People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Helena", "St. Pierre and Miquelon", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (British)", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");

    if( in_array($_GET['guess'],  $countries) {
        echo "Your country $_GET[guess] is valid!";
    } else {
        echo "I'm sorry! You've entered an invalid string!";
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem eventually!
I assigned a variable to `GET` and used this variable in place of `GET` everywhere. This seems to solve the problem!

Answer (score -1):

`$_GET` is array of input parameters (from url). You must take value by name:

```
$_GET['guess']

if($countries[$x]==$_GET['guess'])
```

and use comma for join strings:

```
echo 'Your country ' . $_GET['guess'] . ' is valid!';
```

Comment: Please don't post in haste by missing/omitting important syntax characters.